# Query number of end users using application from oracle database

Tags: oracle

If you could assist with a query that returns number of end-users accessing the application.

The below query returns only the sessions

```
SQL> select count(*) from v$session where status='ACTIVE';

  COUNT(*)
----------
        67

SQL> select count(*) from v$session;

  COUNT(*)
----------
       140
```

Comment: How are these end-users connecting?  Are they sharing the same credentials?  Are they using the same app, and that app actually connecting to the database with its own application credentials?

Comment: There's 2 apps forms and bi which users use different credentials nd apps are connecting to the database with it's own credentials.

Comment: The answer depends on too many variables not specified in your question.  A good way is for your application to be consistent in two rules: (1) that all database access is made through stored packages and (2) that all application package procedures/functions call `DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE`.

But that still might not give you the whole story -- if your application accesses the database through a connection pool and if you define "end users using the application" as "people looking at the application screens on their laptop".  In that case, the database can't answer reliably.

Comment: Your description is not very clear, but it does not sound like you would be able to determine the number of application users this way. This will tell you how many connections are made to the database, but they're very much not the same thing.